# Invalid Hook Call, conversion from function to class

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
export class Register extends Component {
 render() {
    const [selectedGoal, setSelectedGoal] = React.useState(1);
 return (

<RadioButtonRN
                boxStyle={{
                  height: hp("6%"),
                  width: wp("80%"),
                }}
                activeColor="white"
                boxActiveBgColor="red"
                textColor="black"
                textStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                data={goal}
                initial={selectedGoal}
                selectedBtn={(e) => setSelectedGoal(e.id)}
              />
{selectedGoal == 1 ? (
              <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Text style={{ color: "red", fontSize: 15, top: hp("5%") }}>
                  How much would you like to gain per week?
                </Text>
                <RadioButtonRN
                  style={{ top: hp("10%") }}
                  boxStyle={{
                    height: hp("6%"),
                    width: wp("80%"),
                  }}
                  activeColor="white"
                  boxActiveBgColor="red"
                  textColor="black"
                  textStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                  data={details}
                  selectedBtn={(e) => console.log(e)}
                />
              </View>
            ) : selectedGoal == 2 ? (
              <View>
                <Text>Ciao</Text>
              </View>
            ) : (
              <View>
                <Text> you made it</Text>
              </View>
            )})}
```

Hello everyone, I'm new to programming, and I tried using the const under render() for then use it in the RadioButtonRN but of course, it gives me an Invalid Hook Call, how can I convert it to work in my class instead?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you are doing so that we can understand what we're trying to move towards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 problems

1- When component return multiple elements should use fragments for example use

<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>

OR

<></>

Read more on the below link:

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

2- you can use react hook only on the functional components!

change your code to :

```
import React from "react";
export const Register = () => {
  const [selectedGoal, setSelectedGoal] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <>
      <RadioButtonRN
        boxStyle={{
          height: hp("6%"),
          width: wp("80%"),
        }}
        activeColor="white"
        boxActiveBgColor="red"
        textColor="black"
        textStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
        data={goal}
        initial={selectedGoal}
        selectedBtn={(e) => setSelectedGoal(e.id)}
      />
      {selectedGoal == 1 ? (
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Text style={{ color: "red", fontSize: 15, top: hp("5%") }}>
            How much would you like to gain per week?
          </Text>
          <RadioButtonRN
            style={{ top: hp("10%") }}
            boxStyle={{
              height: hp("6%"),
              width: wp("80%"),
            }}
            activeColor="white"
            boxActiveBgColor="red"
            textColor="black"
            textStyle={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
            data={details}
            selectedBtn={(e) => console.log(e)}
          />
        </View>
      ) : selectedGoal == 2 ? (
        <View>
          <Text>Ciao</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View>
          <Text> you made it</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `class` component with react hooks. Hooks only work on functional component but here you are using class. You can read more about it in the docs.
*Example of functional component*

```js
export default function Register() {
 const [selectedGoal, setSelectedGoal] = React.useState(1);

 return <div>{selectedGoal</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `hooks` with React classes. If You construct Your components with classes, then use `state`. Hooks are designed to be use in `stateless` components.

Look here:
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_state.asp

React class state:

```js
class Someclass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
        state_one: 1,
        state_two: 'asd'
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.state_one} // <- usage
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Mind, that You can change `this.state.some_state` like this:

```js
this.setState({some_state: 'new_state'})

// or with using previous state:

this.setState({some_state: this.state.some_state + 1})
```

!!! Watch out for `{}` in `this.setState()`